# postgres system catalog query columns from table

Tags: postgresql, information-schema, system-tables, catalogs

I am building an integration test against an app that provisions a database for a user. The User created for it is not a super user, and **does not** have access to schema_information.tables because when I try the following script:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='{schema}'
```

I get a return of 0, as I should since this user does not have permission.

I am trying to query the database to verify the tables and the columns created. I can get the list of table names through the system catalog with the following script:

```
SELECT tablename
FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables
WHERE schemaname = '{schema}'
```

And this outputs the table names the way I want it:

> business, location, person, etc...

I can't find the script with system catalog to then find the column names (**And as a bonus, the data type**) of each table. So far I've tried the following:

```
SELECT attname, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS type
FROM pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'business'
```

and here is the error:

````
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type oid: "business"
LINE 1: ...od) AS type FROM   pg_attribute WHERE  attrelid = 'business'
                                                         ^```
````

Also tried:

```
SELECT
    a.attname as "Column",
    pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as "Datatype"
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE
    a.attnum > 0
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
    AND a.attrelid = (
        SELECT c.oid
        FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
        WHERE c.relname ~ '**Dont know what to put here, Schema? Database?**'
            --AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
    );
```

and this returns 0 with a schema or database. I'm not sure what to put there for c.relname. Am I also seeing 0 with this because a basic user just cannot see deeper than tables in a schema, period?

Comment: You want to use `'business'::regclass`, I believe.

Comment: I also tried using ::regclass, and it delivered the same error as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select from [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) instead.

```
SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='{schema}';
```

## FOR GLORY

For whatever reason, if you can't query `information_schema.columns` (which would otherwise indicate something is funky to me). We can reverse engineer the catalogs efficiently with `psql -E` with a user that can. Then run the appropriate client (`\`) command in `psql` that shows you what you want, like `\d schema`. And copy out the parts of the exported query you need..

For me the final column in that is something like

```
SELECT a.attname,
  pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
  (SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
   FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
   WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid AND d.adnum = a.attnum AND a.atthasdef),
  a.attnotnull, a.attnum,
  (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_catalog.pg_collation c, pg_catalog.pg_type t
   WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation) AS attcollation,
  NULL AS indexdef,
  NULL AS attfdwoptions
FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
WHERE a.attrelid = '1024334' AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
ORDER BY a.attnum;
```

Now I just need to get all the `attrelid`'s for the schema. Running a quick `\d asdofkodskf` I see,

```
SELECT c.oid,
  n.nspname,
  c.relname
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relname ~ '^(asdofkodskf)$'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 2, 3;
```

We actually want `n.nspname` not `c.relname`

So given my version of `psql`, the official method of querying the catalog directly would be...

```
SELECT c.oid,
  n.nspname,
  c.relname, t.*
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT a.attname,
    pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
    (
      SELECT substring(pg_catalog.pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) for 128)
      FROM pg_catalog.pg_attrdef d
      WHERE d.adrelid = a.attrelid
        AND d.adnum = a.attnum
        AND a.atthasdef
    ),
    a.attnotnull, a.attnum,
    (
      SELECT c.collname
      FROM
        pg_catalog.pg_collation c,
        pg_catalog.pg_type t
      WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation
        AND t.oid = a.atttypid
        AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
    ) AS attcollation
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
  WHERE a.attrelid = c.oid
    AND a.attnum > 0
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
) AS t
WHERE n.nspname ~ '^(public)$'  -- YOUR SCHEMA HERE
AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid);
```

Excerpt (without all the columns or all the rows) (relname is table, attname is column)

```
   oid   | nspname |           relname           |       attname        |       format_type       
llation 
---------+---------+-----------------------------+----------------------+-------------------------
--------
 1024242 | public  | spatial_ref_sys_pkey        | srid                 | integer                 
 1045853 | public  | product_discount_qty_excl   | qty                  | int4range               
 1024334 | public  | valid_detail                | valid                | boolean                 
 1024334 | public  | valid_detail                | reason               | character varying       
 1024334 | public  | valid_detail                | location             | geometry                
 1045847 | public  | product_discount            | pid                  | integer                 
 1045847 | public  | product_discount            | qty                  | int4range               
 1045847 | public  | product_discount            | percent_modifier     | real                    
 1024569 | public  | geography_columns           | f_table_catalog      | name
```